# Adapt QLabel size by QHBoxLayoutSize with scroll area

Tags: python, pyqt

I can't adapt my QLabel size based on QHBoxLayout size.

I have

[image]

I want

[image]
Following code creates scroll panel:

```
def __get_camera_scroll_area(self):
    scroll_area = QScrollArea()
    camera_widget = QWidget()
    camera_layout = QHBoxLayout(camera_widget)
    for i in range(40):
        image_label = QLabel()
        image = QImage("test2.jpg")
        image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
        camera_layout.addWidget(image_label)

    scroll_area.setWidget(camera_widget)

    return scroll_area
```

Comment: You want the height of the QLabel to match the height of the QScrollArea so that the vertical scrollbar does not appear

Comment: yes, i want to disable vertical scroll. Adapts only by height